# pandas extract substring of column and put in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have this column:

```
C-042-00000017276
F-099-00000201997
F-98-204009
```

I want this column to be:

```
C-42-17276
F-99-201997
F-98-204009
```

I know how to extract the data through regex expression and I can solve it iterating over rows, But I want to do it more pandas style:

I am trying this for extract the pair of digits of the string between the '- symbols.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'-.*',df['column'].str.extract(r'(-.*-)',expand=False).str.replace('-','').str.lstrip('0'))
```

but I get:

```
TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")
```

any suggestion with that?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. _I know how to extract the data through regex expression and I can solve it iterating over rows, But I want to do it more pandas style_ I don't think that using regex here would be unidiomatic, especially since Pandas offers some convenient methods for working with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Series.str.replace` for this with `positive lookbehind`.
Basically what we want is to replace one or more zeros (`0+`) if it's preceeded by a dash `(?<=-)`:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('(?<=-)0+', '')

        column
0   C-42-17276
1  F-99-201997
2  F-98-204009
```